# How to hide virtual products from woocommerce orders and cart page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I have created an appointment booking website for car detailing and also want to sell car related products,so I have created my account page with woocommerce so that customers can see their orders and all.But if someone tries to books an appointment and the booking gets canceled or the customer cancels it his own the pending order or canceled order shows in “My account- Order section” also in cart as well.

So as these are virtual products and I have a dedicated booking plugin(Booknetic) to show the bookings,I want the virtual products to be hidden in “My account- orders” section.
Is there any solution? Please help.

[image: Orders section screenshot]

[image: Cart Page Screenshot]

I am not that good at coding so I didn’t try much but with proper instructions I can manage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.